# What should I do with automatic flags about identical posts?

Tags: support, answers, flags, duplicate-answers

Sometimes I find automatic flags about identical answers (I guess they are automatic, as I am not a moderator, and there isn't a flagging reason for identical answers). For example, the following flag is reporting that [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7541/how-can-add-a-textfield-to-user-register-page-form-in-drupal-7/12947#12947) is identical to [this other answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8284/programmatically-create-fields-in-drupal-7/12939#12939), both given from the same user.

[image: screenshot]

Effectively, the answer given in a question is the carbon copy of the answer given in the other question, but the questions are different: Adding a Drupal field is different from adding a textfield.

What am I supposed to do in these cases? I verify if the questions are not duplicates, and if they are not duplicates, I flag the flag as invalid. Is there something more I should do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That flag is indeed automatically generated by the system; so... if you think the answer is fine and applies to both questions, and the question *itself* wouldn't benefit from a merge/close-as-duplicate, then sure: just disagree.

Occasionally, we get a *spate* of someone adding the same answer to every recent question in, say, a particular tag (typically, spamming it). If that isn't the case, then fine!