# Show duplicate posts to 10K users in /review

Tags: feature-request, review, 10k-tools, duplicate-answers

Now that the [10K flag queue is gone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226092/lets-get-rid-of-the-10k-flag-queue), we should put hard working 10K users with lots of experience to work on more problems and be smarter about how.

An obvious candidate for starting this would be the automatically generated "duplicate post" flags. The [current tools for duplicate answers aren't very smart](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122761/please-auto-merge-duplicated-identical-post-flags) - they've barely been given any love since then and they now get less eyeballs.

My suggestion for this would be a workflow that encourages "deep dive" research to split the duplicates into a few cases:

1. They're straight up spam
2. The questions are duplicates
3. The questions are bad
4. The situation really does make sense
5. Something else(?)

If the workflow makes users identify which case applies first and then direct the actions there's not much that can't be done by high rep users. The actions per case then would be:

1. Is it a one off? Are there other posts/users doing the same? Flag spam, job done.
2. Pick master duplicate, delete one answer, job done.
3. Close questions, maybe delete answers, job done.
4. Comment, edit and move on.
5. Flag other and escalate.

As it stands only the first and last actions benefit from mod tools, but most of that is just [grunt work searching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/106579/153020), which could be partially scripted. (By which I mean the advanced searches that are normally useful can be pre-generated based on the post and suggested to reviewers)

More importantly though, some of that really needs domain expert knowledge, particularly the selection of duplicates and sometimes the editing. These functions would benefit from 10K users instead of a handful of moderators looking at things.

Comment: As more of a cleaning type I've taken to spending a minute extra on "bad" questions asked with tags where I have domain knowledge (and a gold badge) trying to find a dupe. Even though I can VTC in seconds it's a lot more satisfying to get them gone in one vote.