# Free answer duplication checking! Free it, I tell you! Good day, sir! I said good day!

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, duplicate-answers

Answer duplication checks apparently only check if an answer is [a duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110136/what-should-i-do-with-automatic-flags-about-identical-posts/) of the answerer's own previous answers.  Well, that's fine 25% of the time, when it's a spammer.

However, we have a decently large problem with plagiarism.  I've seen many instances this week where a user copies, verbatim, another answer.  If it wasn't for our superawesome kewl user base, we'd never know.

Can we open up dupe checking for all users' answers?  I know, I know.  Lots of cycles.  Maybe do it only for low rep users? (pfft, under 10k?  Noob.)  And only for new answers?

Look at what the current state of dupe checking does to maudlin monkey.  Look.

[image]

Maudlin monkey is maudlined by plagiarism.  Let's unmaudlin him.

Comment: Damnit, he isn't maudlined.  He's... oh, what's the word... sounds like a bitter fruit you'd be served at your last breakfast.  Damnit.

Comment: Good day, sir! I said good day!

Comment: Also post an auto comment by Community (after 5 mins, to avoid ninja edits) with a link to the plagiarized content... public shaming is the only way to deal with them. They'll either delete their content immediately (win) or heavily rephrase it to differentiate it (again, win).

Comment: Not just users copying answers verbatim, but also users copying *questions* verbatim! Now *that's* question duplication.

Answer (score 14):

It really rubs me the wrong way when I see users copy and paste verbatim answers into another question as an answer. It doesn't make the Internet a better place, and it doesn't take the effort I'd expect to see in order to increase one's reputation.

The problem is not just limited to low rep or new users though. Awhile back, I recall a user, whose reputation was 20K+, copy and pasted his answer verbatim from an answer he posted not 1 hour prior, as a new answer on a question which happened to be asked by the same user.

The correct answer in this case would have been to downvote and vote to close. Not break the Internet by filling it with more clutter.

In order to be effective for higher rep users without bogging down the system, we could limit the checks to just a 24 to 48 hour period or compare the posted answers to those posted by the same user.

Let's make that monkey happy!

Comment: The system generates a list of related and linked posts, it may be worth it to limit the search for duplicates to those posts. When I've found instances of this, usually the offender is lazy and uses those links to find free reputation.

Comment: Meta statutes *require* that somebody now plagiarize this answer.